# How can I make a Random Number function occur after <div> object reverts to its original location?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So this is for a single serving site, the idea is to swipe the card over the area, and you get certain messages depending on how you interact with the droppable space. What I need to know what to do is add an **if else** function that uses random number variable to have 2 different functions occur. 
So whenever the out: function() executes, either you get the message:

"Please swipe again at this website to enter"

or

another function occurs where certain divs are hidden and is made to appear. (I have some code in the snippet I am working with that I think is close)

I am sorry if my lexicon of coding is off, I am very new to this. Thanks for the advice.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
     containment: 'body', 
        revert:  function(dropped) {
             var $draggable = $(this),
                 hasBeenDroppedBefore = $draggable.data('hasBeenDropped'),
                 wasJustDropped = dropped && dropped[0].id == "droppable";
             if(wasJustDropped) {
                 // revert, it's in the droppable
                 return true;
             } else {
                 if (hasBeenDroppedBefore) {
                     // don't rely on the built in revert, do it yourself
                     $draggable.animate({ top: 0, left: 0 }, 'slow');
                     return false;
                 } else {
                     // just let the build in work, although really, you could animate to 0,0 here as well
                     return true;
                 }
             }
        }
    });
    
    
    
    

    $("#droppable").droppable({
     over: function() {
            $(this).find('p').html('Reading...');
        },
        
        out: function() {
            $(this).find('p').html('Please Swipe Again At This Website To Enter');
        },
        
        revert: function() {
            $(this).find('p').html('');
        },

        drop: function() {
            $(this).find('p').html('Error Reading Your Card');

        }
      //  random generated function I am trying to make
       /*   $("#droppable").droppable({
     over: function() {
            $(this).find('p').html('Reading...');
        },
        
        out: function() {
        var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
     
      if (number == 2) {
       $('#draggable, #draggable2, #droppable, #upperSwiper, #swiper').hide();
       $('#hi').show();
      } else {
       return true;
         }, */
    });
});
```

```css
#hi {
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: none;
 }
 

div.blackBar {
 position: relative;
 background-color: black;
 width: 200px;
 height: 23px;
 top: 75%;
 }

div.frontSwiper {
 background-color: /* #A9A9A9 */ transparent;
 width: 85%;
 height: 65px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
 z-index: ;
 border-radius: 10px;
 }
 
body { 

 width: 90%; 
 height: 90%;
 margin: auto; 
 
 }
 
#swiper {
 background-color: /* #b8b8b8*/ transparent;
 width: 34%;
 height: 75px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative; 
    Top: 200%;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
 }
 
#upperSwiper {

 background-color: transparent;
 width: 34%;
 height: 75px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative; 
    Top: 5%;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 0px;
 }
 
#droppable { 

 width: 200px;
 Height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 border-Width: 1px;  
    background-image:none;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    top: 10%;
    
 }
 
#draggable, #draggable2 {
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 width: 200px; 
 height: 130px;  
 border-Width: 0px;
 background-image:none;
 left: 75%;
 background-color: #FFD700;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 91% 0, 100% 14%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
 clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 91% 0, 100% 14%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
 z-index; -1;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="swiper">
 <div class="frontSwiper"></div>
 <div id="upperSwiper"></div>
</div>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
 <div class="blackBar"></div>
    <p></p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p style="font: italic bold 30px/40px Arial, Sans-serif; width: 50%, position: fixed;"></p>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the `deactivate` or `drop` event. When that event is triggered you will want to check the x/y position and confirm that it matches the starting x/y.

http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: Thanks, but I do not quite understand what you are trying to tell me. (I am New to all coding languages, so bear with me.) Are you saying make it a different function type all together?

I want these 2 functions and then have one of them be executed randomly when the $("#droppable").droppable({ out: function() is executed. [continued...]

Comment: The first function simply state a phrase in the #droppable in the <p> area & returns the object to the original position ( I have this code working..) OR let the second function fire, wich will hide specific <div>s and making another <div> appear. 
<br>
I think I can do this with a random number generator and using the variable in a if else statement, but I do not know exactly how to set it up properly.